# How to add line number at the beginning of each line when contents are written to a new file

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I have the below code,

I am trying to combine contents of two files into a third file and i want to add line numbers at the beginning of each line in the third file.

I have combined the contents of two files into a third file , please find below the code , but  i need to add line numbers at the beginning of each line , please help me.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <conio.h>
# include <process.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *f[2],*fp,*f3;
    char ch;
    int i;
    char file[2][20]={"E:/Structure.txt","E:/Text.txt"};
    char thirdfile[20];
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        fp=fopen(file[i],"r");
        f[i]=fp;
        if(fp==NULL)
        {
            printf("Cannot open file");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    printf("Enter the file to combine contents:");
    scanf("%s",thirdfile);
    f3=fopen(thirdfile,"w");
    if(f3==NULL)
    {
        perror(thirdfile);
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        while(!feof(f[i]))
        {
            ch=fgetc(f[i]);
            fputc(ch,f3);
        }
    }
    fcloseall();
    getche();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int line_number = 0;

for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    int start_of_line = 1;

    while( (ch = fgetc(f[i])) != EOF )
    {
        if (start_of_line)
            fprintf(f3, "%d: ", ++line_number);  /* put line number in output file */

        fputc(ch,f3);
        start_of_line = ch == '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, be sure to +1 and mark as the answer if it worked for you.  Glad I could help!

Comment: BTW, if your first file might not end with a newline, you can fix that by adding this `if` statement after the `while` statement:  `if (!start_of_line) { fputc('\n',f3); }`  That will put in the missing newline between files, if and only if the first file didn't end with one.